# MuleSoft REST API invoking SOAP Service

Tags: rest, soap, mule, anypoint-studio

I invoke a SOAP Service that calls data from a DB using a REST Service, when I call the GET function it returns all null values and the Anypoint Studio Console returns this answer:

INFO  2020-11-19 08:51:40,897 [[MuleRuntime].uber.03: [userstory12_soap].getCustomerByLastName.BLOCKING @393df87f] [processor: ; event: bb2e3fd0-2a76-11eb-9a6c-86c5a63076bd] org.apache.cxf.wsdl.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean: Creating Service {http://client.internal.soap.mule.org/}ProxyService from class org.mule.soap.internal.client.CxfClientFactory$ProxyService

I do not know why is it not working, since I compared my flows with those of a colleague and they are exactly the same (except for some minor variations in variable names). Any input in solving this would be great! Find below screenshot of my flows and XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<mule xmlns:wsc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/wsc" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation" xmlns:db="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:apikit-soap="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/apikit-soap" xmlns:ee="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/apikit-soap http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/apikit-soap/current/mule-apikit-soap.xsd http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core/current/mule-ee.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db/current/mule-db.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/wsc http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/wsc/current/mule-wsc.xsd">
    <http:listener-config name="api-httpListenerConfig">
        <http:listener-connection host="0.0.0.0" port="8087"/>
    </http:listener-config>
    <apikit-soap:config httpStatusVarName="httpStatus" name="soapkit-config" port="us12SOAP" service="us12" wsdlLocation="SOAPUS12.wsdl"/>
    <db:config name="Database_Config" doc:name="Database Config" doc:id="176ab101-fa7d-4ee9-aca3-5c0bf9fe8c77" >
        <db:mssql-connection host="localhost" port="1433" user="sa" password="Gecegu0722@" databaseName="EAIS_Training" />
    </db:config>
    <wsc:config name="Web_Service_Consumer_Config" doc:name="Web Service Consumer Config" doc:id="0665000a-d19d-4801-a118-2315417e9290" >
        <wsc:connection wsdlLocation="api\SOAPUS12.wsdl" service="us12" port="us12SOAP" address="http://localhost:8087/us12/us12SOAP/" >
            <wsc:web-service-security actor="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/actor/next" />
        </wsc:connection>
    </wsc:config>
    <flow name="api-main">
        <http:listener config-ref="api-httpListenerConfig" path="/us12/us12SOAP">
            <http:response statusCode="#[attributes.protocolHeaders.httpStatus default 200]">
                <http:body>#[payload]</http:body>
                <http:headers>#[attributes.protocolHeaders default {}]</http:headers>
            </http:response>
            <http:error-response statusCode="#[attributes.protocolHeaders.httpStatus default 500]">
                <http:body>#[payload]</http:body>
                <http:headers>#[attributes.protocolHeaders default {}]</http:headers>
            </http:error-response>
        </http:listener>
        <apikit-soap:router config-ref="soapkit-config">
            <apikit-soap:attributes><![CDATA[#[%dw 2.0
              output application/java
              ---
              {
                  headers: attributes.headers,
                  method: attributes.method,
                  queryString: attributes.queryString
            }]]]></apikit-soap:attributes>
        </apikit-soap:router>
    </flow>
    <flow name="getCustomerDB:\soapkit-config">
        <db:select doc:name="Select" doc:id="75cdc0ea-04b6-429f-a022-9152c14d1dd9" config-ref="Database_Config">
            <db:sql ><![CDATA[SELECT * FROM customer_aux WHERE last_name = :last_name]]></db:sql>
            <db:input-parameters ><![CDATA[#[output application/java
ns ns0 http://www.example.org/us12/
---
{
    last_name: payload.body.ns0#getCustomerDB.last_name
}]]]></db:input-parameters>
        </db:select>
        <ee:transform>
            <ee:message>
                <ee:set-payload><![CDATA[output application/java
ns ns0 http://www.example.org/us12/
---
{
    body: {
        ns0#getCustomerDBResponse: {
            id: payload.id,
            first_name: payload.first_name,
            last_name: payload.last_name,
            birth_date: payload.age,
            street: payload.street,
            city: payload.city,
            country: payload.country,
            phone: payload.phone
        }
    } write "application/xml"
}
]]></ee:set-payload>
            </ee:message>
        </ee:transform>
    </flow>
    <flow name="getCustomerByLastName" doc:id="0b351b65-af46-414b-9ac6-ccf02812e2d2" >
        <http:listener doc:name="Listener" doc:id="72239ecd-26b9-4a81-90a0-6a486e396eb8" config-ref="api-httpListenerConfig" path="/getCustomerByLastName"/>
        <wsc:consume operation="getCustomerDB" doc:name="Consume" doc:id="d29f381b-d054-4a03-8255-f953ce6996ed" config-ref="Web_Service_Consumer_Config">
            <wsc:message >
                <wsc:body ><![CDATA[#[output application/xml
ns ns0 http://www.example.org/us12
---
{
    ns0#getCustomerDB: {
        last_name: attributes.queryParams.last_name
    }
}]]]></wsc:body>
            </wsc:message>
        </wsc:consume>
        <ee:transform doc:name="Transform Message" doc:id="8a2b6eb1-d798-4f73-a25b-a74f54eeb8ce" >
            <ee:message >
                <ee:set-payload ><![CDATA[output application/json
ns ns0 http://www.example.org/us12/
import * from dw::core::Strings
---
{
    id: payload.body.ns0#getCustomerDBResponse.id default 0,
    firstName: capitalize(payload.body.ns0#getCustomerDBResponse.first_name) default "",
    lastName: capitalize(payload.body.ns0#getCustomerDBResponse.last_name) default "",
    age: payload.body.ns0#getCustomerDBResponse.birth_date default "",
    street: capitalize(payload.body.ns0#getCustomerDBResponse.street) default "",
    city: capitalize(payload.body.ns0#getCustomerDBResponse.city) default "",
    country: capitalize(payload.body.ns0#getCustomerDBResponse.country) default "",
    phone: payload.body.ns0#getCustomerDBResponse.phone default 0
}

]]></ee:set-payload>
            </ee:message>
        </ee:transform>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, screenshots of flows provide very little value to understand an issue. The XML would be more helpful because it contains all the details. You should check if the DB query is returning the expected results, the response from the WS is correct and if the transformations match your expected results too. Add loggers after each operation to trace that. Also you can enable HTTP wire logging to see exactly what the request and responses contain: https://support.mulesoft.com/s/article/How-to-Enable-HTTP-Wire-Logging
The log entry showed is an INFO level log, not an indication of an error per se.

Comment: Sorry, I thought I added it before, but I corrected it in the edit! Thanks for the insight

Comment: Thanks. I don't see anything obviously wrong. Maybe the DB query is not returning anything? Try logging the information or debug to understand what could be happening.